# Move content from one git repository to another, and deploy with capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, deployment, capistrano

I have two .git repositories:

```
/var/git/repo_a.git
/var/git/repo_b.git
```

They get deployed with capistrano into:

```
/var/www/rails/repo_a
/var/www/rails/repo_b
```

I want to migrate all the content of repo_b.git into repo_a.git, removing the content of repo_a.git. After that, I want to deploy repo_a.git into repo_a directory without problems.

But I'm afraid of this... I wanna be sure everything will still work out!
What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Why can't you just clone b onto your local machine, delete a from git(hub) and then commit your changes?

Comment: Those two repositories are the same application... one for production, the other for testing. The testing application has been deeply modified and now is time to bring it in production... The switch will happen through an automated procedure... I will create a batch file scheduled with crontab.

Comment: We've just done a similar migration and are suffering thereafter! Good luck :)